# How to get following output using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Basically, one code that derives the following string:

```
Su2330-6&12-18,M0030-6,Tu9-17,Th6-15,F6-15
```

The letters represent days of the week

e.g.

```
Sunday = Su
Monday = M
Tuesday = Tu
Wednesday = W
Thursday = Th
Friday = F
Saturday = Sa
```

And the numbers represent times (e.g `2330-6 = 23:00pm-06:00am`)

What I need it to do is, where there are consecutive days with the same working hours, the days needs to be separated by a '/' followed by times. So in the example I’ve given, Thursday and Friday have the same hours so the string should look like

```
'2330-6&12-18,M0030-6,Tu9-17,Th/F6-15'.
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: 1. You never gave us your input. 2. You haven't showed us what you've tried and what isn't working. 3. There are infinitely better ways to store this data.

Comment: As stated, this is not a SQL question. In a database, you should have all the data in proper tables, with the data separated into rows and columns, with each column having a meaningful name and a proper data type. What you are asking is to take something that is already exceptionally bad and to make it worse still. The main question here is not "what" or "how" but WHY???

Comment: This is really not the right way to store scheduling information.  I would suggest one row per time period and then build the string up from there.

Comment: hi, honestly I don't know what to use. I mentioned input and expected output format in my question. will it be possible for you to help me?

Comment: You did not mention input. If you want a SQL query, it has to pull from at least one table. What does the table look like? Are there multiple tables? How do they connect together? This is needed at a minimum.